# What is the difference between DocumentRoot and Directory in apache2 for mac os x

Tags: apache-2.2

I am now setting the virtual hosts in my local environment in Mac OS 10.9.2
I am copying this from another configuration.
My question is, what is the difference between DocumentRoot and Directory, do they have to match? Do I have to include Directory inside my VirtualHost config?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/Users/memyselfandi/websites/prestashop16.dev"
   ServerName prestashop16.dev

   ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/prestashop16.local-error_log"
   CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/prestashop16.local-access_log" common

   <Directory "/Users/memyselfandi/websites/workspace/dev">

                            AllowOverride All
                            Order allow,deny
                            Allow from all
    </Directory>

 </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 11):

[DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#documentroot) is the location on your web server from which the web server will serve files if a user visits http://prestashop16.dev/. All of your web-visible files should be at or below that folder's level.

The [Directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) block lets you specify Apache configuration rules that should only apply to a specific directory.

The two do not have to match, and a `<Directory>` block can be placed within a VirtualHost block or in the general server config, according the the Apache docs.

Also, you can have multiple Directory blocks. For example, if your DocumentRoot was `var/www` and you wanted to restrict access to `/var/www/private` you could create `<Directory /var/www/private></Directory>` block and place your desired security configurations in there without affecting other folders.

Comment: So to clarify, you have one DocumentRoot per VirtualHost, and any Directory in the VirtualHost must be a subdirectory of the correponding DocumentRoot ?

Comment: No. The ``Directory`` directive applies configurations to a directory and its subdirectories. As such, ``Directory`` can be any path (full system path). More specific paths' configs will take precedence. Since Apache serves content from the DocumentRoot, it makes little sense (to the best of my knowledge) to define ``Directory`` directives for dirs other than your DocumentRoot's base dir or subdirs.

Comment: Actually, thinking a bit more about it, it makes sense to define ``Directory`` directives for paths outside your DocumentRoot, if such paths are invoked from ``Alias`` directives (this directive allows to serve content not stored under the DocumentRoot).