# Apache2 docroot and the directory directive in apache2.conf

Tags: apache-2.4, directory, documentroot

Why is in standard `apache2.conf` only the container directive `<Directory /var/www/>` instead of the docroot `<Directory /var/www/html>`?

I have the following release:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

And I am using `apache 2.4`.

Comment: It might depend on your linux distribution.  For example, the default value for DocumentRoot is /usr/local/apache/htdocs, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot . Could you provide some additional information about your linux distribution?

Comment: Yes, of course. I can provide some additional information. Please view my edit.

Comment: There's a pretty good explanation here: https://serverfault.com/questions/588380/what-is-the-difference-between-documentroot-and-directory-in-apache2-for-mac-os

Main thing from it is that Directory lets you specify config rules that pertain to that directory while docroot just specifies where to pull files from when visiting that vhost. It doesn't matter if it's in apache2.conf or in a site config file.